# Typescript function with argument of type property of Interface

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Is there a way to use a property/key of an interface as a function argument type?

For example, if I have an interface:

```
interface column{
   id: string,
   title: string,
   description: string
}
```

and I have a function:

```
const replaceColumnProperty = (col: column, property: string, val: string) => {
   col[property] = val;
}
```

Typescript complains that type string does not match column interface.

It should be:

```
const replaceColumnProperty = (col: column, property: 'id' | 'title' | 'description', val: string) => {
   col[property] = val;
}
```

However, my interface has 20 properties. Is there a way to avoid having to write a constant for each interface property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the keys of an object-like type:

```
const replaceColumnProperty = (col: Column, property: keyof Column, val: string) => {
  col[property] = val; // okay
}
```

And you can verify it works the way you want from the call side too:

```
const col = { id: "", title: "", description: "" }
replaceColumnProperty(col, "id", "id"); // okay
replaceColumnProperty(col, "oops", "oops"); // error!
// ----------------------> ~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"oops"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Column'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA2BXAtiZAbwFgAoZZYAEwC5kBnMKUAcwBoyKxgxMI7GzEO07IqEegmYAHbuhACmrMgF8yZBPMbIoEaZkQQMOfAAUo6adDABPZAF5kACk2Y6xvCDbJpFq1Fs6AGsIG3QYNCxPbwA3ODcGJWEASgcAPiJRVwBtX0trGwBdB2Q4zABuVXVSTRBtVxLCSlpkACJW725efjaOsQkpYFlgeTp25DVSXX1DDzM-Apcsb1bqPtWqVuTy5AB6XeR0ILgbMmmDJDmQc3yAmyXMFfRLenXn6VftvYPoCygAQjI+2QAFoweCIZCoSCMgA-eEIoEHACCUBYeAg4EOEVsVmQAHJWu9XvjKPRkCB0GBkHB6PRgCwQHAAEZ8ZBgdA+OBQOC4CCQKDY9k2PH4kJhCJXfEAOmqZCAA)